# Discord rich embed buttons

Tags: python, discord.py

I made a few discord.py bots, but I came across one which was surprising. It's called IdleRPG and uses rich embed messages with buttons. Here's a pic (note the buttons at the bottom of the menu):

[image]

I've tried contacting the developer and been searching the net but can't seem to find how they did it. Does anyone know of any resources on how to create them? Please provide links.

Comment: Those buttons bellow are discord reactions... You can check them out in the discord.py documentary

Comment: Can I add the reaction within the embed itself and not just beneath it like in the picture? I wish to use it like a button for my commands.

Comment: Here's an example of a simple pagination system using discord reactions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51796005/reaction-pagination-button-forward-and-back-python/51801449#51801449

Comment: I don't think adding reactions inside an embed is possible...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update:** Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65336328/11146632) answer for the latest version of `discord.py`.

---

Here you go... I was able to create a command that edits the embed on reaction clicks:

**Program:**

```
@client.command()
async def embedpages():
    page1 = discord.Embed (
        title = 'Page 1/3',
        description = 'Description',
        colour = discord.Colour.orange()
    )
    page2 = discord.Embed (
        title = 'Page 2/3',
        description = 'Description',
        colour = discord.Colour.orange()
    )
    page3 = discord.Embed (
        title = 'Page 3/3',
        description = 'Description',
        colour = discord.Colour.orange()
    )

    pages = [page1, page2, page3]

    message = await client.say(embed = page1)

    await client.add_reaction(message, '⏮')
    await client.add_reaction(message, '◀')
    await client.add_reaction(message, '▶')
    await client.add_reaction(message, '⏭')

    i = 0
    emoji = ''

    while True:
        if emoji == '⏮':
            i = 0
            await client.edit_message(message, embed = pages[i])
        elif emoji == '◀':
            if i > 0:
                i -= 1
                await client.edit_message(message, embed = pages[i])
        elif emoji == '▶':
            if i < 2:
                i += 1
                await client.edit_message(message, embed = pages[i])
        elif emoji == '⏭':
            i = 2
            await client.edit_message(message, embed=pages[i])
        
        res = await client.wait_for_reaction(message = message, timeout = 30.0)
        if res == None:
            break
        if str(res[1]) != '<Bots name goes here>':  #Example: 'MyBot#1111'
            emoji = str(res[0].emoji)
            await client.remove_reaction(message, res[0].emoji, res[1])

    await client.clear_reactions(message)
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

For accepting a page number you'll have to create an if statement for that emoji and use the `wait_for_message()` function. Then you'll have to check whether the page number is valid and change the value of `i` accordingly.

I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Great answer @Sujit, what's the best way to not get the asyncio.TimeoutError though?

Comment: @echan00 I have written an answer for the latest version of `discord.py` here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65336328/11146632

Answer (score 5):

I've already written an answer for this question, however that answer is for an older version of `discord.py`. Seeing that this question gets a large number of views, I've decided to write an answer for the latest version of `discord.py`.

**Program:**

```
@client.command()
async def embedpages(ctx):
    page1 = discord.Embed (
        title = 'Page 1/3',
        description = 'Description',
        colour = discord.Colour.orange()
    )
    page2 = discord.Embed (
        title = 'Page 2/3',
        description = 'Description',
        colour = discord.Colour.orange()
    )
    page3 = discord.Embed (
        title = 'Page 3/3',
        description = 'Description',
        colour = discord.Colour.orange()
    )
    
    pages = [page1, page2, page3]

    message = await ctx.send(embed = page1)
    await message.add_reaction('⏮')
    await message.add_reaction('◀')
    await message.add_reaction('▶')
    await message.add_reaction('⏭')

    def check(reaction, user):
        return user == ctx.author

    i = 0
    reaction = None

    while True:
        if str(reaction) == '⏮':
            i = 0
            await message.edit(embed = pages[i])
        elif str(reaction) == '◀':
            if i > 0:
                i -= 1
                await message.edit(embed = pages[i])
        elif str(reaction) == '▶':
            if i < 2:
                i += 1
                await message.edit(embed = pages[i])
        elif str(reaction) == '⏭':
            i = 2
            await message.edit(embed = pages[i])
        
        try:
            reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout = 30.0, check = check)
            await message.remove_reaction(reaction, user)
        except:
            break

    await message.clear_reactions()
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

For accepting a page number you'll have to create an if statement for that emoji and use the `wait_for()` function. Then you'll have to check whether the page number is valid and change the value of `i` accordingly.

I hope you get the idea.

Comment: awesome, will try this out instead

Answer (score 0):

## Don't use reactions as buttons.

Reactions have to be added one at a time, which can be excruciatingly slow. Discord is currently implementing actual buttons, which you may already see in bots such as Dank Memer and Dyno. As we currently wait for discord.py 2.0 to be released for button support, we can already implement buttons with a python module called `discord_components`.

You can get help with that here in my other answer: [Add button components to a message (discord.py)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67722188/add-button-components-to-a-message-discord-py/68638949#68638949)

This is a recommendation, you don't need to do this but it's better than using reactions.