# Add button components to a message (discord.py)

Tags: python, api, discord.py

I was wondering after seeing [this](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/message-components) (message components) on discord's API reference if there was any way to implement it using python ?

> I tried making a json array and passing it in my message but couldn't make it work.
>
> I also tried looking on the reference for python but couldn't find anything.

Here's my code

```py
components= [
  {
    "type": 2,
    "label": "Clear les kick",
    "style": 4,
    "custom_id": "clear_kick_button"
  }
]
@slash.slash(name="kicked", description="Voir qui a été kick et combien de fois.", guild_ids=guild_id)
async def kicked(ctx):
  await ctx.send("test", components= components)
```

If you have any informations thank you if you share it.

Comment: Don't mind the name of the command just used an unfinished one to test the components.

Comment: Please remove the discord.js tag if you're not using js

Comment: Also, discordpy already manages all the components for you. You will not need to make your own. Just look at the [discordpy docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). Not discord's

Comment: Doesn't look like it's implemented yet, you might need to try using `requests`

Comment: @FluxedScript, dont use requests with bots. It blocks event loops

Comment: @DNA Yes `aiohttp` would be better for a bot but they probably don't run a large bot so `requests` would suffice.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## New Answer

---

Discord.py 2.0 Allows for use of Buttons and Dropdowns, and has new added support for Slash Commands. A 3rd party repository is no longer necessary. However, if you don't want to use the default one for some reason, you can checkout `discord_slash`.

To upgrade to Discord.py 2.0:

Windows:

```
pip install -U git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py
```

MacOS and Linux:

```
pip3 install -U git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py
```

## Old Answer:

## (This Answer is OUTDATED.)

---

## As of right now, you can get a library called `discord_components` to use buttons.

To install this library, use `pip install --upgrade discord-components`  (Sometimes the command would be `pip3 install --upgrade discord-components`).

To import Discord Component Buttons, use

```
from discord_components import DiscordComponents, Button, ButtonStyle, InteractionType
```

Then just add this code in the bot's `on_ready()`:

```
DiscordComponents(bot, change_discord_methods=True)
```

(Make sure to replace `bot` with the name of your bot, the same one you use for `@something.command()`)

To add a button to a message, do this:

```
await ctx.send(type=InteractionType.ChannelMessageWithSource, content="Message Here", components=[Button(style=ButtonStyle.URL, label="Example Invite Button", url="https://google.com"), Button(style=ButtonStyle.blue, label="Default Button", custom_id="button")])
```

(A message is required)

To do something when the button is clicked, you can do something like this:

```
@bot.event
async def on_button_click(interaction):
    if interaction.component.label.startswith("Default Button"):
        await interaction.respond(type=InteractionType.ChannelMessageWithSource, content='Button Clicked')
```

This method even survives reboots!

Here's an example I put together for you if you need it:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_components import DiscordComponents, Button, ButtonStyle, InteractionType

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix, description="Desc", help_command=None)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    DiscordComponents(bot, change_discord_methods=True)
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name=f"{prefix}help"))
    print("Bot has successfully logged in as: {}".format(bot.user))
    print("Bot ID: {}\n".format(bot.user.id))

@bot.command()
async def button(ctx):
    await ctx.send(type=InteractionType.ChannelMessageWithSource, content="Message Here", components=[Button(style=ButtonStyle.URL, label="Example Invite Button", url="https://google.com"), Button(style=ButtonStyle.blue, label="Default Button", custom_id="button")])

bot.run("token")
```

Hope this Helps!

Tip: If you want the buttons to be in one row, use [[]] instead of just [] for Example: [[btn1, btn2],[btn3, btn4]] will result in:

```
[btn 1][btn 2]
[btn 3][btn 4]
```

Extra Tip: You can also set a variable as a button then send the variable

Comment: An update with how to "end " the interaction (disable the buttons) and check that the user that started the interaction is the one that pressed the buttons would be good.

Comment: @PepeOchoa It already exists you should check out the "check" argument in "bot.wait_for" on the API reference.

Comment: discord.py already has buttons implemented in the latest read only version. I don't see the usage of a third party library for the sole purpose of adding something DPY already has

Comment: @Shom77 I know that this post was made while 2.0 was being implemented. Now I would suggest discord_slash, it supports buttons, slash command, selects, and it can even auto-sync your existing commands. No need to shame me for posting something that is now outdated. (Also, D.py 2.0 only supports buttons, not slash or dropdown)

Comment: I'm not trying to shame you at all, just that I don't see the purpose of a third party library now.

Also, D.py 2.0 allows dropdowns, I used them today for my bot

Comment: The creator of discord.py stated that with the current structure of DPY, he couldn't incorporate slash commands.

However, the entire discord UI exists on discord.py besides slash commands, hence why I don't see why this answer shouldn't be edited to add discord.py's latest version (v2.0) for the majority of discord's UI.

Comment: Because I'm 13 and You're asking a kid to edit the answer into something of which I have no idea how to do, Stack Overflow really isn't the place for debates like this. If you must, message me on discord instead. Eric Pan#0001

Comment: `pip install discord —update` command is not working. Also when I use `pip install --upgrade discord` it says `Requirement already satisfied: discord.py>=1.7.3`. Is discord.py 2.0 even out?

Comment: @YılmazAlpaslan Discord.py 2.0 is out, I just got the command wrong, my bad!

Comment: @Eric `no such option: --update` still wrong code lol. But `--upgrade` option either doesn't updates discord.py to 2.0.

Comment: @YılmazAlpaslan use pip install -U git+github.com/Rapptz/discord.py

Comment: @Eric `ERROR: Invalid requirement: 'git+github.com/Rapptz/discord.py'`

Comment: @YılmazAlpaslan Not sure about that, Command works for me? When I do print(discord.__version__) it prints 2.0

Comment: oh i see stack overflow is removing the HTTP in my message
pip install -U git+https:// github.com/Rapptz/discord.py

Comment: @Eric thanks lol i already noticed it and installed it by adding http. Btw discord.py 2.0 is awesome thanks for letting me know!

Comment: Discord.py version 2 cannot install via pip. So what do I need to do when I host the discord bot via Github --> Heroku ?

Comment: I think in requirements.txt you just add git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py

Comment: I think y'all should use enhanced-dpy, it also supports slash commands and latest features of Discord, such as autocomplete etc.

Comment: is that a fork of discord.py?

Comment: Yeah, it is....

Answer (score 4):

Here is an **example** of the *Alpha version* from `discord.py` as it is not implemented yet:

```py
import discord

class Counter(discord.ui.View):
    @discord.ui.button(label='0', style=discord.ButtonStyle.red)
    async def counter(self, button: discord.ui.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        number = int(button.label)
        button.label = str(number + 1)
        if number + 1 >= 5:
            button.style = discord.ButtonStyle.green

        await interaction.message.edit(view=self)

view = Counter()
await ctx.send('Press to increment', view=view)
```

- Another example can be seen here: [Tic-Tac-Toe](https://gist.github.com/Rapptz/dbfd8cd945a9245e5504a54c2b9eda03)
- To check the status I would take a look at the [repository](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py) itself.

Comment: Note: In recent versions the placement of the button and interaction parameters were swapped: `self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button`

Answer (score 2):

I would like to say that this page is 3 months old, discord_components has changed a lot, Interaction Type does not exist anymore, please follow this

https://gitlab.com/discord.py-components/discord.py-components/-/tree/master/examples

Answer (score 1):

There is a Library named discord.py-message-components.
You can install that trough 
`python3 -m pip install -U git+https://github.com/mccoderpy/discord.py-message-components.git@developer`
You can do there anything. 
SlashCommands, SelectMenus, Button, Modals and much more. 
You need to uninstall discord.py and install this library.

The Docs are here: https://docs.discord4py.dev/. 
It will named discord4py soon.

To create a Button:

```
import discord
from discord import SlashCommand
from discord import ButtonStyle, Button

@bot.slash_command(name="kicked", description="Voir qui a été kick et combien de fois.", guild_ids=guild_id)
async def kicked(ctx: discord.ApplicationCommandInteraction):
    components = [ActionRow(Button(
        label="Clear les kick",
        custom_id="clear_kick_button",
        style=ButtonStyle.gray
    ))]
    await ctx.send("test", components=components)
```

Answer (score 0):

Buttons are not yet implemented in the [Discord.py Wrapper by Rapptz](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py) as of the currently newest version [v1.7.2](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/whats_new.html).

---

You can however look up [here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/projects) what is scheduled for the next update, and what the status of development is.

In the meantime you will have to either make own requests to the Discord API, or search for unofficial libraries.

Comment: This answer is now outdated, as Discord.py 2.0 is now available. Check out my answer for how to install it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67722188/add-button-components-to-a-message-discord-py/68638949#68638949

Comment: Not quite correct. It is true you can get a site-package for buttons, however Discord.py 2.0.0 was never officially released, and sadly Discord.py is no longer being maintained. Have a look at the [wiki-page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/discord.py/info).

Comment: Found how to install it. pip install -U git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py Source is the Official Discord Server Announcements, even though it's not an official release.... YET

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little section of a code I wrote, I'm also new to this Discord components but hopefully this helped you with your issue.

```
await ctx.channel.send("Context",components=[Button(style=ButtonStyle.blue, label="Test")]) #Blue button with button label of "Test"
    res = await self.client.wait_for("button_click") #Wait for button to be clicked
    await res.respond(type=InteractionType.ChannelMessageWithSource, content=f'Button Clicked') #Responds to the button click by printing out a message only user can see #In our case, its "Button Clicked"
```

Also to remember to import the components first.

```
from discord_components import DiscordComponents, Button, ButtonStyle, InteractionType
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming by your decorators you're using `discord-py-slash-command`

If that assumption is correct, you can't natively use components with that library. [`discord-py-components`](https://github.com/kiki7000/discord.py-components) adds that functionality while we wait for `discord.py 2.0` to be released