# Rich Embed Buttons in Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I wanted to know how to add buttons to Rich Embed Messages for my Discord bot in Discord.py
Like this:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKfP1.png)

Comment: I've never seen anything like that in my 3 years on discord.

Comment: They were introduced 2-3 days ago @TreeBen77

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add button components to a message (discord.py)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67722188/add-button-components-to-a-message-discord-py)

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not implemented yet in Discord.py, it will be for the 2.0 (this is what is planned for the moment), but there is already few libs that make it. [A good one is that of kiki700, Discord-Components](https://github.com/kiki7000/discord.py-components)

Comment: Do you have any idea when Discord.py 2.0 is getting released

Comment: You can go to their server for more information, but in a few months a priori.

Comment: I would suggest using discord-interactions because discord-components doesn't support slash command sending

Answer (score 1):

You can add a emoji with the Text and add a reaction to the Embed.

for example:

```
    if message.content.startswith(begin + "help"):
    embed = discord.Embed(title='{} Needs Help'.format(message.author),
                          description='Help for {}'.format(client.user.name),
                          color=message.author.color)
    embed.add_field(name="Title", value='description', inline=True)
    embed.set_footer(text="Bot by orty")
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=message.author.avatar_url)
    msg = await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
    await msg.add_reaction(client.get_emoji('Custom Emoji ID'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I useing the buttons in discord too, because they are nice.
I also had a problem like this and I finaly use this code:

```
ticket = await channel.send(
    "_ _",
    components = [
        Button(label = "YOUR NAME", style=ButtonStyle.blue, emoji=""),   
    ]
)
await client.wait_for("button_click", check = lambda i: i.component.label.startswith("YOUR NAME"))
await test.respond(content="hello")
```

So this is my Code. You dont have to use a emoji in front but I think its nice.

Comment: I'm assuming this is the discord-components library?