# AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'ui'

Tags: python, discord.py

Question title defines the issue. I install the `discord.py` module with this following:

`pip install -U git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py`

However, when I try to run my code:

```py
import discord

class JoinQueue_Button(discord.ui.View):
    @discord.ui.button(label='Join This Game!', style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
    async def queue(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        current_queue = {}

        await interaction.user.id
```

I get an error saying the `ui` module does not exist. I am unsure what to do at this point.

Comment: Do you have a local file of your own named `discord.py`?

Comment: No, I don't. Do I need one?

Comment: No, in fact you shouldn't have one.  But if you did, that could explain this error.

Comment: Is this helping you? [Add button components to a message (discord.py)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67722188/add-button-components-to-a-message-discord-py). What you are trying to do is in `v2.0` of `discord.py`

Comment: `discord-ui` is a separate package from `discord`.

Comment: If this is the case then how come I do not see a declaration for ``discord-ui`` in this example? https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/views/counter.py

Comment: I assume because `discord-ui` installs as a sub-package of `discord`, so you only need the one import.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be outdated.

Try and run the next command: pip install --upgrade discord.py

Comment: Tried this as well, and got the same issue. I've been uninstalling and reinstalling all day.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

- **Windows**:    `py -m pip install discord-ui`
- **Linux**:   `python3 -m pip install discord-ui`

Also check [here](https://libraries.io/pypi/discord-ui)

Comment: Do I need to add ``import ui`` anywhere as well?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem running this

```
python3 -m pip install -U py-cord --pre
```