# Buttons in a message, discord

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

How do I add buttons to my welcome message?
button switch to another channel

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = client.get_channel(channelID)
    await channel.send(f'Hello')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add button components to a message (discord.py)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67722188/add-button-components-to-a-message-discord-py)

Comment: I do not need to use a command, I just need to add one button to my message that the bot sends automatically when greeting new members

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For buttons I use [`discord-py-slash-command`](https://pypi.org/project/discord-py-slash-command/) package ([documentation](https://discord-py-slash-command.readthedocs.io/en/components/index.html)).

```py
from discord_slash.utils import manage_components
from discord_slash.model import ButtonStyle

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = client.get_channel(channelID)

    button = manage_components.create_button(style=ButtonStyle.URL, label="Your channel", url=f'https://discord.com/channels/{member.guild.id}/{channel.id}')
    action_row = manage_components.create_actionrow(button)
    
    await channel.send(content=f'Hello', components=[action_row])
```

This will create a button that will forward you to your channel.
**Link consists of:** `https://discord.com/channels/<server_id>/<channel_id>`

[image]

[Read more about Discord buttons](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/message-components#buttons)

Comment: thank you but I get an error, I imported the library from the documentation you sent pip install -U discord-interactions and it didn't help. > https://ibb.co/k5xLMGk

Comment: I need to install - discord_components ?

Comment: And pip install discord-py-slash-command ?

Comment: @Dmitriy you don't have to install `discord-interactions`. You just need `discord-py-slash-command`. Install it with: `pip install discord-py-slash-command`

Comment: I'm new, so I asked you.  How to make a button without a link?  just click on it and go to the channel

Comment: I don't think there is any other possibility to do it. You can mention the channel using `<#channel_id>`, but it's not a button it's just a mention in a text message. Also, why you don't want to use the link?

Comment: Thanks! how to mention the channel I know) I just thought it could be done without a link