# Not able to import discord.ui library

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to use discord.ui library to create buttons with my discord bot. The problem is that I'm not able to import the library. I updated discord.py through Github `pip install -U git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py`, I even installed discord-ui separately `pip install discord-ui` but it still doesn't work. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Did you check this out?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67722188/add-button-components-to-a-message-discord-py

Comment: Oh, I just found that it works with Python 8.0+ interpreter but not with Python 10.0+ because Python 8.0+ is using discord.py 2.0+ but Python 10.0+ is using discord.py 1.7.3. How I'm able to update the 10.0 interpreter? It updates automatically the older one for some reason.

Comment: Nevermind, it doesnt work either.

Comment: Ok, i managed to import discord.ui, im able to im port Button, bot not View for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to use this? https://pypi.org/project/discord-ui/

Then you have to import `discord_ui`.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. You probably are using discord.py and that is a good start, but the UI kit is not working beacuse the PIP package install is installing the 1.7.3 version and the UI kit is only running on 2.0.0 version. You can install the 2.0.0 with this command:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py
```

You need git installed, however, and for me I was getting me error, so I discovered that there exist's another library called py-cord that is atualizated and in 2.0.0, by default is the same as discord.py (you don't need to change anything); even the import you don't need to change:

```
import discord # is fuction py-cord
```

If you are using the py-cord, you need to uninstall discord.py first, then follow this [simple and easy documentation](https://guide.pycord.dev/introduction).