# Discord.py: Guild object has no attribute create_scheduled_event

Tags: discord.py

Discord.py is handy to automate things and I am trying to create a scheduled discord event by command. But it seems that I cannot call the function `create_scheduled_event` of the Guild object while other functions work fine.
For example, the function `fetch_roles()` works fine and returns the roles of my guild.
But calling the function `create_scheduled_event` raises the error `'Guild' object has no attribute 'create_scheduled_event'`.

Does anybody have an idea what I am missing, here?
Thanks in advance!

Here's the code

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # ...
    
    if message.content.startswith('!newevent'):
        myguild = client.guilds[0]
        roles = await myguild.fetch_roles()
        print(roles)
        newevt = await myguild.create_scheduled_event(...)

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Try [upgrading to discord.py 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68638949/16136190). The version you're using probably doesn't have [`Guild.create_scheduled_event`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.create_scheduled_event). If it doesn't work even after upgrading, please [edit] your question to include a [mre] that contains `guildsindahouse`'s definition.

Comment: Thank you! Although I followed the documentation from the git repo, version 1.7.2 got installed. So your hint helped and the function can be called. Sadly this breaks a lot of my previous code. So it's migration time.