# Scrolling down in a discord.py embed

Tags: discord.py, embed

[This is my embed rn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEjH8.png)

It uses the google API to get upcoming events on a calendar but I have to limit the number of events it gets since the message will be too long. The list of calendars is stored in the description of the embed. Is there any way to limit the embed to a certain size and be able to scroll down in the description so all events can be displayed?

Comment: There's no scrollbar feature for embeds but I guess you can use emojis in order to create multiple embed pages. You can check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61793587/13892965) answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **Zimano** said, you can't have scrollable elements in embeds, but what you can do is a multi-page embed, the easiest approach would be with `ext.menus` (To install it: `python -m pip install -U git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord-ext-menus`)

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import menus

class MultiPageEmbed(menus.ListPageSource):
    async def format_page(self, menu, entry):
        return entry


@bot.command()
async def whatever(ctx):
    # Put all your embeds here
    embeds = [discord.Embed(title="Embed 1"), discord.Embed(title="Embed 2"), discord.Embed(title="Embed 3")]

    menu = menus.MenuPages(MultiPageEmbed(embeds, per_page=1))
    await menu.start(ctx)
```

Unfornatelly it's still in beta so there's no docs about it.

Comment: Here is my current code how would I adjust?
```client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
      return
   if msg.startswith('$events'):
        events = event()
        poggers=discord.Embed(title="Events", url="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/3?cid=Y180OXZpYmEycWpjZzE5dHIydmYyM21hOWJpNEBncm91cC5jYWxlbmRhci5nb29nbGUuY29t", description=events, color=0x00ffff)
        poggers.set_footer(text="Events Calendar")
        await message.channel.send(embed=poggers)```

Comment: Sorry if i looks confusing I cant seem to figure out proper format in comments

Comment: But I think you can figure out how to make it work, good luck!

Answer (score -1):

No, you can't add scrollable elements in embeds.