# Problem with sending embeds for help command with pages

Tags: python, discord.py

I was following [I want to make a multi-page help command using discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61787520/i-want-to-make-a-multi-page-help-command-using-discord-py) but wanted to have embeds instead of messages for my help command. So far for testing I have..

```py
@commands.command()
async def help(self, ctx):
        oneembed=discord.Embed(title="test1", color=0xAF0735)
        twoembed=discord.Embed(title="test2", color=0xAF0735)
        contents = [oneembed, twoembed]
        pages = 4
        cur_page = 1
        message = await ctx.send(embed=f"{contents[cur_page-1]}")
```

When i type the help command, it sends
`Page 1/4: <discord.embeds.Embed object at 0x0000018E68E98C10>`

How can I get this to send the actual embed instead of the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass it as an embed like this

```py
await ctx.send(embed=contents[cur_page-1])
```

[`TextChannel.send`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=send#discord.TextChannel.send)

Comment: I get this error `Ignoring exception in command help:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\colee\Documents\GitHub\Guard\cogs\MiscCommands.py", line 24, in help
    message = await ctx.send(embed=f"{contents[cur_page-1]}")
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\abc.py", line 1017, in send
    embed = embed.to_dict()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_dict'`

Comment: The first page in you code is an embed but other pages are strings, you have to make them all embeds.

Comment: I have updated my code.. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: You were using f strings which will make the embed a string I have updated my code.